# Automate OS installation and associated packages

Tags: software-installation

We are having a small software firm and we are using ubuntu for our employees. Whenever a new machine bring to our office, we do install ubuntu, and many required packages such as LAMP,skype,IDEs,filezilla etc and integrate the machine to our AD using likewise etc. So every time we do it manually and we need an effective way to do this. I need something automated or create an iso from the existing one (fully installed machine) that can be used for the installation afterwards.

Comment: I reinstall a lot of different versions, but just created a bash script to automate just about everything. But if hardware is identical you may be able to use something like Clonezilla? http://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntu Customization Kit (UCK) to create your own customized Live CD/DVD/USB.  Then you can use that CD, DVD, or USB to install your own customized Ubuntu onto other machines.

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux-utils libfribidi-bin uck
```

(I've also included a couple of important required packages in the above command).

Here is the UCK Launchpad Page: https://launchpad.net/uck

After you install the `uck` package, there are a two bugs you should apply fixes for:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/uck/+bug/1245981

https://bugs.launchpad.net/uck/+bug/1435019

After installation, launch the UCK GUI from the Unity Dash.  Select your language preferences, and then select the "Run Console Application" option, so you can install your required software (LAMP, Skype, IDEs, filezilla etc.) using `apt-get` and make necessary configurations.

(Note that the final compressed iso may not be greater than 4GB, but you should have plenty of space to install all the software you need).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something straightforward you must use remastersys , although it is discontinued there is a way to install it on ubuntu 14.04 . Two steps and you just wait until your iso is ready to burn.

http://www.diolinux.com.br/2014/04/remastersys-no-ubuntu-1404LTS.html

This step by step  is in portuguese but i can help if you need . After install just type in terminal to create a distro including all your programs and updates:

```
sudo remastersys dist
```

Or to include your home folder and configs

```
sudo remastersys backup
```